# Calling Audioparam methods with periodic time

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I would like to call *AudioParam* methods 'atTime' periodically so that they are called periodically when playing audio loop. So, for example, in method  *linearRampToValueAtTime()*, I can only specify a given time, but not a period of time. Is there a way to do it?

I need it to make a loop in which I fade out with *GainNode* at the end, and fade in again at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule AudioParams as far into the future as you like with the time you like.

Something like

`for (time = 0; time < endTime; time += interval) {
  // Fade out
  gain.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, time, timeConstant);
  // Fade in
  gain.gain.setTargetAtTime(1, time + fadeInTime, timeConstant);
}`

This should fade out the signal at time `interval*k` seconds and fade it in at time `interval*k+fadeInTime`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Well, the problem is that I was planning to allow loops to be paused, so I should recalculate fadeInTime every time there is a pause and a play, and it would cause some problems in the case of pausing

Comment: You'll have to describe what you want in more detail.  Don't know what you mean by "cause some problems in...pausing".

Comment: Sorry, it was incomplete: "in the case of pausing in the 'fading zone' ". If we pause in a given time between 'time' and 'fadeInTime'. When we play again, how de we resume the fading? We could calculate the gain in that moment. But I think there should be an easier way to solve that (I am afraid there is not)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you're trying to do.  If you're playing again, why do you want to resume the fading?  And right now you have to calculate the gain yourself.  However, if cancelScheduledValues() were spec'ed to cancel  and hold, perhaps this would work for you.

Comment: It's a problem different from the question. Say you program a fade out from seconds 4 to 6. If you press pause in second 5, you want to continue fading out when you press play. But setTargetAtTime will not work because time is relative to audioContext.currentTime which continues to count regardless of whether audio is playing or paused. So you need te recalculate everything by yourself.

Comment: Ok, now I have a better understanding.  If the spec were updated to say cancelScheduledValues() also holds, then you could say cancelScheduledValues(5) to stop the ramp, but also hold the last value at time 5. Then when you restart, you could do setTargetAtTime(0, ....) to continue the ramp where you left off.